# python/twisted - what is wrong with this code?

Tags: python, twisted

I am learning Python and am focused on Twisted at the moment...I am working on a tutorial exercise, butI can't seem to grasp why the modification in the second version of this code is causing the 'count' function to execute before the reactor has started. all that has been changed is adding the 's' argument to the function.

working:

```
class Countdown(object):

counter = 5

def count(self):
    if self.counter == 0:
        reactor.stop()
    else:
        print self.counter, '...'
        self.counter -= 1
        reactor.callLater(1, self.count)

from twisted.internet import reactor

reactor.callWhenRunning(Countdown().count)

print 'Start!'
reactor.run()
print 'Stop!'
```

broken:

```
class Countdown(object):

counter = 5

def count(self,s):
    if self.counter == 0:
        reactor.stop()
    else:
        print self.counter, '...'
        self.counter -= 1
        reactor.callLater(1, self.count(1))

from twisted.internet import reactor

reactor.callWhenRunning(Countdown().count(1))

print 'Start!'
reactor.run()
print 'Stop!'
```

here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\twistedexample\basic-twisted\countdown.py", line 15, in <module>
    reactor.callWhenRunning(Countdown().count(1))
  File "C:\Python27\twistedexample\basic-twisted\countdown.py", line 11, in count
    reactor.callLater(1, self.count(1))
  File "C:\Python27\twistedexample\basic-twisted\countdown.py", line 11, in count
    reactor.callLater(1, self.count(1))
  File "C:\Python27\twistedexample\basic-twisted\countdown.py", line 11, in count
    reactor.callLater(1, self.count(1))
  File "C:\Python27\twistedexample\basic-twisted\countdown.py", line 11, in count
    reactor.callLater(1, self.count(1))
  File "C:\Python27\twistedexample\basic-twisted\countdown.py", line 11, in count
    reactor.callLater(1, self.count(1))
  File "C:\Python27\twistedexample\basic-twisted\countdown.py", line 7, in count
    reactor.stop()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 580, in stop
  "Can't stop reactor that isn't running.")
  ReactorNotRunning: Can't stop reactor that isn't running.
```

any input on this is appreciated, I feel like I'm missing something important here and don't want to just skip over it.

Comment: You should fix your indentation in the code example, as presented it's a syntax error :)

Comment: oops! Didn't notice. I'll fix it here shortly. Loving Twisted still, by the way

Comment: Thank you, kind of you to say so :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version of the code passes a reference to the function `count` (so that it can be called at a later time), whereas the broken version of the code passes the *result* of the function call of `count(1)`, which is going to be `None` (as `count` has no `return` value). So what you've essentially done is changed this:

```
reactor.callWhenRunning(Countdown().count)
```

to this:

```
reactor.callWhenRunning(None)
```

and on top of that you are *immediately* calling `count(1)` instead of registering it for a later call! This explains the error you are seeing, as the countdown is running before you ever reach the line `reactor.run()`.

The same applies to the line `reactor.callLater(1, self.count(1))` which is calling `count(1)`, probably returning `None`, and not actually registering any function with `callLater`.

Comment: I'm not following...the count is still called, it prints out from 5 to 1 before hitting the error...how can it be doing that if the initial callWhenRunning is using None?

Comment: Try it without the line `reactor.run()` and I'm guessing it will still count from 5 down to 1, even though the reactor was never started! Basically you are kicking off the `count` function _within_ the line `reactor.callWhenRunning(Countdown().count(1))`; it has nothing to do with the reactor anymore, the inner part of that line, i.e. `Countdown().count(1)` will first result in `count` running.

Comment: To be clearer, `count` is a reference to the `count` function; it doesn't run anything. `count()` _runs_ the `count` function. And `count(1)` _runs_ the `count` function with an argument of 1.

Comment: I think I see. So how might I pass that variable without kicking off the count function? The goal of the exercise is to start off multiple countdowns of different lengths - I am trying to use 's' as a starting point to count down from to replace the 'counter' variable of the working code.

Comment: You pass them in like this instead: `reactor.callWhenRunning(Countdown().count, 1)`. Be careful though, as your `count` function is somewhat recursive as it calls itself and may not do what you intend!

Comment: that's exactly what I needed to know man, thanks a bunch! this was one of those tricky ones I couldn't put into words to try and Google, but I could tell it was something fundamental I was missing. thanks again for the quick and helpful response